# Mysql Switch case returning incorrect results

Tags: mysql

Consider the following row in my mysql table:

```
id   Url   Urls
6433       ["https://do.foo/", "https://do.foo/2"]
```

I need to populate url with the first `url` from the `urls` column wherever it is empty. So I ran this query:

```
select coalesce(url, '') = '' as `is_true` ,
convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR) as `extracted`,
case url
    when coalesce(url, '') = '' then convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR)
    else '3'
end as `valid_url`
from table_name where id = 6433 ;
```

The result was:

```
is_true      extracted          valid_url
1            "https://do.foo/"  3
```

Is there any reason the extracted url to not show up in the valid url column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression is incorrect. When you write `CASE column WHEN expression` as you have done, the value in `column` is compared against the expression, so in your case you are comparing `url` (which is `NULL`) against `''`, which fails. Either change your `CASE` expression to the `CASE WHEN expression` form, or change `url` to `COALESCE(url, '')` and the expression to `''`. For example:

```
select coalesce(url, '') = '' as `is_true` ,
convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR) as `extracted`,
case 
    when coalesce(url, '') = '' then convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR)
    else '3'
end as `valid_url`
from table_name where id = 6433
```

or

```
select coalesce(url, '') = '' as `is_true` ,
convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR) as `extracted`,
case coalesce(url, '')
    when '' then convert(JSON_EXTRACT(urls, '$[0]'), CHAR)
    else '3'
end as `valid_url`
from table_name where id = 6433
```

In both cases the output is:

```
is_true     extracted           valid_url
1           "https://do.foo/"   "https://do.foo/"
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=61c937379e25f744d35419cf11e7168e)